# deleting records with parameter

Tags: vb.net

how do you add a parameter after this code so that I can delete the records ininteger data type: here is the code.

com = New OleDbCommand("DELETE * FROM Products WHERE Product = '" & DataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells(0).Value.ToString & "'", con1)

I keep getting a message that the data type is mismatched

Comment: take datagridview value on label and pass that label value in where condition.. which datatype is use for that variable?

Comment: This doesn't look like the question I answered earlier.  Did you delete the original contents of your question and replace it with a new question?  Do you really think that that is a sensible way to use this site?  If your question has been answered then accept the answer and if you have a new question then post a new question.  As it stands, anyone who finds this page from the web will wonder what the hell is going on because the answers have nothing to do with the question.

Comment: sorry about that.....

Answer (score 0):

You have no `WHERE` clause in your SQL code.  If you don't specify a `WHERE` clause then you are referring to every record.  You have to use the `WHERE` clause to specify WHICH record to update.  That's what the primary key is for.

Answer (score 0):

You must need a **Where** clause in your SQL Statement to distinct the row for edit else it can change all.

Answer (score 0):

You must use `where` clause in that it update only that record which you want..if you don't use `where` clause it update all records.
for more information of update you use this [link](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_update.asp)